# Trying to un-toggle elements while toggling another and displaying different text as other elements are toggled, codepen in description

Tags: html, jquery, css, toggle

I want to have a simple read more and read less button functionality where if one button is clicked then it will show the text and when another is clicked it will hide the previously opened and so on but I have been unsuccessful in changing the button text as each is changed e.g. when it says read more and when I click it changes to read less, then when I click another button it is still displaying read less.

Here is my example of what I have done so far https://codepen.io/Niall_Caffrey/pen/abNavaj

```js
    $('body').on('click', '.shownow', function() {
  
    $(this).parents('.main').find('.notshow').addClass('nohide').toggle();
  
       $('.notshow').each(function() {

          if (!$(this).hasClass('nohide')) {

              $(this).hide();
            
          } else {
            
              $('.notshow').removeClass('nohide');
              
          }
      });
  
   

    if($(".notshow").is(":hidden")){
               $(this).text("Read More");
               $('.notshow').addClass('showhide');
               $('.main').addClass('showhide');
            };
        
           if($(".notshow").is(":visible")){
             $(this).text("Read Less");
             $('.notshow').removeClass('showhide');
             $('.main').removeClass('showhide');
          };
    });
```

```css
    .notshow {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .main{
      width:25%;
      float:left;
    }
```

```html
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <h3>How it is done</h3>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="notshow">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <div class="shownow">
                <p class="btn">Read More</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="notshow">
           <p>lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <div class="shownow">
                <p class="btn">Read More</p>
            </div>
        </div>
       
    </div>


    <div class="main">
        <div class="notshow">
           <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <div class="shownow">
                <p class="btn">Read More</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: When you are writing 'Read More' you are doing it to 'this' which is the button that has just been clicked, not the button that was previously clicked.. You need to write the Read More at the time you make the previous button's associated text not display.

Comment: This is not your main problem I think, but to note that you are overwriting the p button element so that after the first click it no longer exists, this is because of what $(this).text... does

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how to make clickable/togglable buttons that correctly both hide the text and relabel the button of any previously clicked button.

I am not familiar with jquery and I couldn't completely follow the given code, except to note that the writing of 'Read More' was going to 'this' which is the most recently clicked element, not the previous one. I also noted that the way 'Read More/Less' was being written using jquery text overwrote the button (a p element) so it was only there up until the user did the first click.

Keeping the structure of HTML but replacing the onclick function with the code below seems to work. This is deliberately written in naked JavaScript so as not to introduce errors such as the use of text in the original.

```
  var previousClicked='';
        
      $('body').on('click', '.shownow', function() {
        
        if (previousClicked!=this) {
          hideTextEl(previousClicked);
        }
          
        previousClicked=this;
          
        if (findTextEl.classList.contains('notshow')) {showTextEl(this);
        } else {hideTextEl(this);}
          
       function hideTextEl(el){
         if (el) {
              el.firstElementChild.innerHTML='Read More';
              findTextEl(el).classList.add('notshow');
            }
        }
        
       function showTextEl(el){
         if (el) {
              el.firstElementChild.innerHTML='Read Less';
              findTextEl(el).classList.remove('notshow');
          }
        }
        
       function findTextEl(el) {
         while (!el.classList.contains('main')) {el=el.parentElement;}
         return el.firstElementChild;//NB if the structure of the HTML changes this may need changing
       }
     });
```